# React Native - Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, expo

I had an app in `Expo` and used `expo eject`.

My app runs fine on `iOS` using `npx react-native run-ios`

Running on Android im having problems, getting the following issue:

```
> Task :unimodules-core:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
362 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 357 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unimodules-core:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
```

In the Directory `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` I have:

[image]

And this is my bash_profile:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/"Android Studio.app"/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
    }
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
    }

    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
}
}
```

my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Tried various stackoverflow posts but Cant seem to fix this issue, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I also started getting this issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with JDK. Have you installed JDK in your system?
Try downloading JDK with v8 and try again. It should run. Try installing particular to 8 if any other is installed.

You can find officiel package from here-

```
https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html
```

Comment: yes - followed the instructions https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup and ran `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`